# Input date in HTML form?

Tags: jquery, html

I know about jquery "date-picker" but cant understand how to implement it.

Id like to use it on a html form inside a table.

one of my fields for the form is

```
"<tr><td>Name: </td> <td><input type='text' id='name'/> </td> </tr>" +
```

Id like a similar one but for date input.

Comment: You could start by looking at the examples in the docs... http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Comment: Try to read documentation examples : http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't really understand where did you stuck in because you didn't show any code of your attempts but this is how it's being done:

```
$(function() {
    $("#name").datepicker();
});
```

Don't forget to include the `css` and `js` files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: for OP: make sure you can include all required files like jquery-ui.css, jquery core file, jquery-ui.js file.

Comment: 1 last question, is it better to download the css and js files, then use src locally or just simply use the on-line ones?

Comment: @user1261083. The on-line files will make the download of your pages shorter, because they're widely used, and download already. this is the reason it's out there... Good luck!